# Get array of same object from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, object

the first one is a global list of products (say 10 products) that each product contains a code and a quantity greater than or equal to 0. (this is important)

the second is a list of products (say 3) that each product contains a code (the same as in the first table) and a quantity equal to 0.

I want to filter the first array and have an array with 3 product but keep the quantities of the first one
for example:

```
   state.Data = [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "1",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "2",
            "qte": "14"
        },
        {
            "code": "3",
            "qte": "14"
        },
        {
            "code": "4",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "5",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "6",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "7",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "8",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "9",
            "qte": "0"
        }
    ];
    action.value.Data = [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "2",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "3",
            "qte": "0"
        }
    ];
 // what I want:
    result = [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "qte": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "2",
            "qte": "14"
        },
        {
            "code": "3",
            "qte": "14"
        }
    ];
```

the difference between action.value.Data and result is qte of each product.

I had tried:

```
  const mainData = [...action.value.Data,...state.Data];
  var catData = mainData.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c.code] = (p[c.code] || 0) ;
    return p;
  }, {});
  
  var result = mainData.filter((obj) => {
    return catData[obj.code] >= 0;
  });
nextState = {
  ...state,

  Data: result,
}
```

but the `result` table gives me 6 products instead of 3 (always double) and the `qte` is always 0, so how to filter the `state.Data` array and keep only the products which have the same code as in the `action.value.Data` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not understand the logic of your code actually. Solution is extremely simple

```
// step 1: getting keys
const keys = action.value.Data.map(v => v.code)

// step 2: filter values with these keys
const values = state.Data.filter(v => keys.includes(v.code))
```

That's it

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with one liner. All you want to do is filter the first array checking which items are on the second array:

```js
const result = state.Data.filter(({code}) => 
               action.value.Data.some(x => x.code === code))
console.log(result)
```

You get exactly the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter the global products based on the `code`s in `action.value.Data` but you can also try the below solution to avoid nested loops.

Create a map with `code` as keys, `qte` as values and use it while mapping the `action.value.Data`.

```js
const global = [{
    "code": "0",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "1",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "2",
    "qte": "14"
  },
  {
    "code": "3",
    "qte": "14"
  },
  {
    "code": "4",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "5",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "6",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "7",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "8",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "9",
    "qte": "0"
  }
];
const bla = [{
    "code": "0",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "2",
    "qte": "0"
  },
  {
    "code": "3",
    "qte": "0"
  }
];

const codeVsQty = new Map(global.map(({code, qte}) => [code, qte]));

const result = bla.map(({code}) => ({code, qte: codeVsQty.get(code)}));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const state = {Data:[
   {"code": "0","qte": "0"},{"code": "1","qte": "0"},{"code": "2","qte": "14"},{"code": "3","qte": "14"},
   {"code": "4","qte": "0"},{"code": "5","qte": "0"},{"code": "6","qte": "0"},{"code": "7","qte": "0"},
   {"code": "8","qte": "0"},{"code": "9","qte": "0"}
]},
 action = {value:{Data:[
   {"code": "0","qte": "0"},{"code": "2","qte": "0"},{"code": "3","qte": "0"}
]}};

const res = state.Data.filter(o=>action.value.Data.some(a=>a.code==o.code));

console.log(res)
```